# Doppler shift of a single photon

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, quantum-optics, doppler-effect

I'm curious to understand how the Doppler shift phenomenon occurs and is mathematically expressed for a single photon emitted by a stationary single photon emitter, such as a quantum dot, and observed by a relatively moving observer (of any type). Is the mathematical expression for the Doppler frequency shift of a single photon different from that of a collection of photons, known as EM wave?

Comment: You might look at red and blue shift measurement for galaxies.  Typically that might consist of light emitted from distant hydrogen in stars. I think most of that is single photon average detection, but not necessarily so.  All other things being equal, I would expect light (of same wavelength) from the same moving emitter to shifted the same.

Answer (score 4):

If your photon has a wave vector $\vec k$ in the lab frame, the it has a covariant 4-vector in the lab:

$$ k^{\mu} = (\omega/c, \vec k) = (k, \vec k) $$

where I have used the dispersion relation:

$$ \omega = c||\vec k||$$

From a moving frame ($\vec \beta$), the four-wave vector is:

$$ k'^{\mu} =\Lambda(\vec \beta)^{\mu}_{\ \nu}k^{\nu} $$

Defining the $z$-axis along the direction of motion, that becomes:

$$k'^{\mu}=\left[\begin{array}{c}
\gamma\omega/c - \beta\gamma k
\\0\\0\\
-\gamma\beta\omega/c + \gamma k
\end{array}\right]
$$

which with the dispersion relation and

$$\gamma^2 = \frac 1 {(1-\beta)(1+\beta)}$$

gives the standard form of the relativistic Doppler shift.

Comment: Thanks. I understand the underlying philosophy here and I enjoyed your neat proof. However, some people may argue that a single photon has no frequency and/or k vector. The reason is that a single photon is in a well-defined Fock state, from quantum perspective, and Fock states are not the eigenstates of the E (electric) operator, leading to undetermined phase and frequency. It would be great if you could kindly comment on this issue as well. Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: Fock states come from a hamiltonian, and are inherently non-relativistic. I suppose you can invert the Glauber State (a coherent wave as a sum of infinity Fock states), and then boost the coherent states.

Comment: Yes, you’re right about non-relativistic nature of Fock states.  Sure, I’ll do it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

A single photon is a standard electromagnetic wave, just one of the minimum amplitude. The Doppler shift is the same as for electromagnetic waves of higher amplitudes.

Comment: Thanks. This represents the common wisdom perspective on the existence of photons. However, it's important to note that while a bunch of photons can create a coherent state with well-defined frequency and phase, a single photon exists in a well-defined Fock state, lacking a precisely defined frequency and phase. Although a photon's energy is represented by "hf", its frequency isn't necessarily "f". This raises the question: how can we justify the Doppler shift phenomenon for a single photon when its frequency and phase aren't well-defined?

Comment: Do you have a reference for this?  Wave packets do have Doppler shifts, if that's what you're talking about.

Comment: @JerroldFranklin Check the wiki page for the Glauber state. Or better, watch Ketterle's MIT open course on YT...it's a full graduate course, though. My quantum optics "expertise" comes from those, and my neighbor  is Amnon Yariv....

Comment: Are you saying that wiki, Glauber, Ketterle, YT, Yariv, and you can describe states that I am not talking about?  Is there a publication, or journal article? The state I am talking about has a pure frequency, which is not rare when talking about electromagnetic waves